# Программа на java не находит файл по указанному пути

Tags: java, файлы

Не получается обратиться к файлу, который лежит не в папке проекта. Вот этот кусок кода выводит "File not found".

```
File settings = new File("C://Users//Admin//workspace//settings.txt");

        if(settings.exists())
            System.out.println("File exists");
        else
            System.out.println("File not found");
```

Comment: Попробуйте указать другой диск. Возможно нет доступа к С.

Comment: Зачем вы удваиваете слэш?

Comment: Потому что ява и не тот слеш =)Правильная запись: `File settings = new File("C:\\Users\\Admin\\workspace\\settings.txt");`, но винда должна переварить и вариант автора =)

Comment: В Java лучше использовать стандартную запись пути: `A/B/C` (так же, как в URL, как в Linix и как в MacOS). На Windows можно также использовать `A\\B\\C`, но не `A//B//C`. PS: понравилась минималистичность вопроса с одновременной понятностью проблемы: не часто такое встретишь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Прямой слеш не надо экранировать (причем экранирование делается обратным слешем), а вы просто задвоили прямой слеш. Так должно работать:

```
    File settings = new File("C:/Users/Admin/workspace/settings.txt");

    if(settings.exists())
        System.out.println("File exists");
    else
        System.out.println("File not found");
```

и так

```
    File settings = new File("C:\\Users\\Admin\\workspace\\settings.txt");

    if(settings.exists())
        System.out.println("File exists");
    else
        System.out.println("File not found");
```

Контруктор File(String) внутри вызывает нормализацию пути `fs.normalize(pathname)`, где `fs` интерфейс `FileSystem`.

JVM знает что работает под Window, и использует реализацию `WinNTFileSystem` и соответствующий разделитель, который берет из свойства JVM "file.separator".

Поэтому должны работать оба варианта